# Representing handlers on UML diagrams

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram, behavior, activity

This question is a follow-up to [Representing multiple actions for sequence of objects on activity diagram](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/367521/representing-multiple-actions-for-sequence-of-objects-on-activity-diagram), but isn't strictly related. The question boils down to:

How to present in UML patterns that behave differently depending on how network of handlers is configured.

In simplest case I have the following:

```
<cfg>
    <handler id="1" />
    <handler id="2" />
</cfg>
```

This means that during execution data will be passed first to *handler-1* and then to *handler-2*. But configuration can be changed so that flow is *handler-2* and then *handler-1*, or even *handler-2*, *handler-1*, *handler-1*, *handler-2*.

And what if handlers can be composed/combined? I can easily create class diagrams for such shenanigans, but activity or sequence diagrams are completely beyond me.

Comment: I'm afraid there's no general pattern that can be applied always. Can you lost specific situations so that through examples you might grasp a better understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a general answer to your question. You have to take the cases one-by-one, since the devil is in the details.

> This means that during execution data will be passed first to handler-1 and then to handler-2.

It's not 100% clear what you mean, but I'll show you two ways to show this in UML with a sequence diagram:

[image: UML Sequence diagram showing data passed to handlers]

> But configuration can be changed so that flow is handler-2 and then handler-1, or even handler-2, handler-1, handler-1, handler-2.

You can use the same notation as above to show each case.

> And what if handlers can be composed/combined?

Again, sequence diagrams are pretty explicit, so you have to be precise. One way you can show general calling of a method inside a list of elements is as follows:

[image: UML Sequence diagram showing data passed to an aggregate of handlers]

As you mentioned, in UML you could (should) complement this with the static structure of the aggregate (composition) of handlers with a class diagram.

If the traversal of the composite structure is complex (i.e., not just a straightforward list or tree iteration), you could diagram it with an activity diagram.

You could check out the UML diagrams for the [Chain of Responsibility pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern#UML_class_and_sequence_diagram), too, since this is related to your question.